All SPFX Web Parts showing Something Went Wrong (Script Error)
I am trying to develop custom SPFX web parts for a Sharepoint site, and all of a sudden all of my web parts stopped working. When putting any of them in a site, it just shows

Something went wrong
If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
TECHNICAL DETAILS
ERROR:
Script error for: cc37eb81-2a57-4583-82da-03cdf1b6a635_0.0.1/HelloWorldWebPartStrings
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

CALL STACK:
Error: Script error for: cc37eb81-2a57-4583-82da-03cdf1b6a635_0.0.1/HelloWorldWebPartStrings
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at B (eval at e (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:8:252)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (eval at e (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:30:244)

The "HelloWorld" in HelloWorldWebPartStrings is replaced with the title of the web part I am trying to load. This is happening in all of my web parts including newly made ones that just have the boilerplate code. This error does not show up in the workbench or while appending "?debug=true&noredir=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js" to the end of the site url.
These are the errors I am getting in the console.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
/sites/Intranetdev/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PersonalCache/ReadCacheOrCreate:1 
        
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
hello-world-web-part.js:1 
        
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
HelloWorldWebPartStrings_en-us.js:1 
        
Uncaught (in promise) Event 
sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:198 

Uncaught (in promise) Event 
sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:198 

2VM581:8 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Script error for: cc37eb81-2a57-4583-82da-03cdf1b6a635_0.0.1/HelloWorldWebPartStrings
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at B (eval at e (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:8:252)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (eval at e (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:30:244)

B @ VM581:8
onScriptError @ VM581:30
sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:199 Could not load hello-world-web-part in require. Error: Script error for: cc37eb81-2a57-4583-82da-03cdf1b6a635_0.0.1/HelloWorldWebPartStrings
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at B (eval at e (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:8:252)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (eval at e (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:30:244)

(anonymous) @ sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:199Understand this error
VM581:8 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Script error for: cc37eb81-2a57-4583-82da-03cdf1b6a635_0.0.1/HelloWorldWebPartStrings
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at B (eval at e (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:8:252)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (eval at e (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_a7662d9c0b1c17f753346b1ddef93a05.js:1:1), <anonymous>:30:244)

Thank you for your help in advance!
